# How remove 'This email was sent using the CakePHP Framework' in cakephp 2.4.x

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I want to know how remove 'This email was sent using the CakePHP Framework' from cakephp.
I have removed this text from `/app/View/Layouts/Emails/html/default.ctp` and `/app/View/Layouts/Emails/text/default.ctp`. But there is no change. Also I have removed it from `/app/View/Emails/html/default.ctp` and `/app/View/Emails/text/default.ctp`. Again no change.
How can I make it?

Comment: just search the string "This email was sent using the CakePHP Framework" over the progect and you will get all the places

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  It's almost certainly in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran an [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) search over a [Cake 2.4.9 installation](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/2.4.9) and found these files containing your line to change/remove:

- app\View\Layouts\Emails\html\default.ctp (line 27)
- app\View\Layouts\Emails\text\default.ctp (line 21)
- lib\Cake\Console\Templates\skel\View\Layouts\Emails\html\default.ctp (line 18)
- lib\Cake\Console\Templates\skel\View\Layouts\Emails\text\default.ctp (line 21)
- lib\Cake\Test\Case\Controller\Component\EmailComponentTest.php (lines 246, 259, 309, 468, 482)
- lib\Cake\Test\Case\Network\Email\CakeEmailTest.php (lines 1277, 1299, 1487, 1491, 1495, 1503, 1514, 1638, 1641)
- lib\Cake\Test\test_app\Plugin\TestPlugin\View\Layouts\Emails\text\plug_default.ctp (line 4)
- lib\Cake\Test\test_app\Plugin\TestPluginTwo\View\Layouts\Emails\text\default.ctp (line 4)
- lib\Cake\Test\test_app\View\Layouts\Emails\html\thin.ctp (line 11)
- lib\Cake\Test\test_app\View\Layouts\Emails\html\default.ctp (line 11)
- lib\Cake\Test\test_app\View\Layouts\Emails\text\default.ctp (line 11)

Those are all the instances of your the notice in an out-of-the-box Cake 2.4.9 install. You should make your own email views and layouts for emails though.

Comment: Are you suggesting changing the contents of the Cake folder? It's poor advice... -1.

Answer (score 14):

You're seeing that output because you're using the standard Email layout files. To remove the text, update the [default email layouts](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.4.9/app/View/Layouts/Emails) provided by CakePHP under:

```
app/View/Layouts/Emails/html/default.ctp
app/View/Layouts/Emails/text/default.ctp
```

If the files don't exist *that's* why you've seeing that text - the fallback is a standard email template also containing that text.

Answer (score 7):

When you set the your template, you have to make sure, you set the second parameter to null.

So don't do:

```
$Email->template('yourTemplate', 'default');
```

do:

```
$Email->template('yourTemplate', null);
```

Comment: That was my case. Custom template. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use SMTP mail options as follows.

```
$this->Email->subject = 'testing cakephp mail'; 
$this->Email->from = 'admin <admin@xyz.com>'; 
$this->Email->to = xyz@gmail.com; 
$this->Email->template = 'xyz';
$this->Email->sendAs = 'html'; 
$this->Email->send();
$this->Email->reset();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.